# Cannot start Spark on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to set up Spark on `Kubernetes` on Mac.  I have followed [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-spark-on-kubernetes/) web pages and it looks so straightforward for me to understand.

Below is the `Dockerfile`.

```
# base image
FROM java:openjdk-8-jdk

# define spark and hadoop versions
ENV SPARK_VERSION=3.0.0
ENV HADOOP_VERSION=3.3.0

# download and install hadoop
RUN mkdir -p /opt && \
    cd /opt && \
    curl http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}.tar.gz | \
        tar -zx hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/lib/native && \
    ln -s hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION} hadoop && \
    echo Hadoop ${HADOOP_VERSION} native libraries installed in /opt/hadoop/lib/native

# download and install spark
RUN mkdir -p /opt && \
    cd /opt && \
    curl http://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz | \
        tar -zx && \
    ln -s spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop2.7 spark && \
    echo Spark ${SPARK_VERSION} installed in /opt

# add scripts and update spark default config
ADD common.sh spark-master spark-worker /
ADD spark-defaults.conf /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/spark/bin
```

After building the Docker image I ran the following commands but the pod doesn't start.

```
$ kubectl create -f ./kubernetes/spark-master-deployment.yaml
$ kubectl create -f ./kubernetes/spark-master-service.yaml
```

**spark-master-deployment.yaml**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: spark-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: spark-master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: spark-master
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spark-master
          image: spark-hadoop:3.0.0
          command: ["/spark-master"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7077
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
```

**spark-master-service.yaml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: spark-master
spec:
  ports:
    - name: webui
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: spark
      port: 7077
      targetPort: 7077
  selector:
    component: spark-master
```

To trace the problem, I ran the `kubectl describe...` command and got the following result.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  45s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/spark-master-fc7c95485-zn6wf to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     21s (x3 over 44s)  kubelet, minikube  Container image "spark-hadoop:3.0.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    21s (x3 over 44s)  kubelet, minikube  Created container spark-master
  Warning  Failed     21s (x3 over 43s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: failed to start container "spark-master": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/spark-master\": stat /spark-master: no such file or directory": unknown
  Warning  BackOff    8s (x3 over 42s)   kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
```

It seems that the container didn't start but I didn't figure out why the pod does not start correctly even though I only followed the instruction on the web page.

Below is the GitHub URL that the web page gives me a guide for configuring Spark on Kubernetes.
https://github.com/testdrivenio/spark-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Minikube.

For minikube make the following changes:

1. Eval the docker env using: eval $(minikube docker-env)
2. Build the docker image: docket build -t my-image
3. Set the image name as only "my-image" in pod specification in your yaml file.
4. Set the imagePullPolicy to Never in you yaml file. Here is the example:

   ```
   apiVersion:
   kind:
   metadata:
   spec:
     template:
        metadata:
           labels:
              app: my-image
     spec:
        containers:
          - name: my-image
          image: "my-image"
          imagePullPolicy: Never
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn’t copy the scripts developed by the blogger which are in [this project](https://github.com/testdrivenio/spark-kubernetes/tree/master/docker), where in the image there is this command `ADD common.sh spark-master spark-worker /`, so your image misses the script you need to run the master (you will have the same problem with the workers), you can clone the project then build the image, or use the image published by the blogger `mjhea0/spark-hadoop`.
Here you are trying to setup a spark standalone cluster on Kubernetes, but you can use Kubernetes itself as a spark manager, where spark in the release 3.1.0 announced that Kubernetes officially become a spark cluster manager (it was experimental since the release 2.3), [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html) is the official documentation, you can also use [spark-on-k8s-operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator), developed by Google, to submit the jobs and manage them on your Kubernetes cluster.